issue with django show image tried many ways to solve
template doest not show images
i use <img src="/static/logo_coorg.png" width="60" height="40">
and settings like :[ changed ]
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL  = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')


and the url as :

urlpatterns = [   
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('erp.urls')),  
    
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

by this way one of my django website does not have any issue. but another new django website is really a desparate one with this error. i am trying to fix this since last 24+ hours.
help is sought.

Could you provide more information, like an image of your directory structure?

@zankoAN sorry i have tried many folder structure for static and media all failed. could u pls suggest the right way.

In your template file, first load the static files with:
{% load static %}

Then use the static template tag:
<img  src="{% static '/logo_coorg.png' width="60" height="40" %}"

When your DEBUG mode is False, you don't need to add URL patterns for MEDIA_URL or STATIC_URL because Django is not responsible for serving your static or media files. You can write it like this:
from django.conf import settings


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

You should handle the media and static URL paths inside the Apache webserver config file to serve the static and media files. For example:
Alias /media/  full_path_of_your_media_diractory
<Directory full_path_of_your_media_diractory>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
    
Alias /static/ full_path_of_your_static_diractory  
<Directory full_path_of_your_static_diractory>
    Require all granted
</Directory>



Check the slashes in the URLs (I might be wrong).

If it still doesn't work, please add your directory structure and webserver configuration to the question.

thank you. the problem was only the permission missing in the .conf.
actually i  had included. yet the folder link was given wrong. thank you again.
